# How to model optional self dependence in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to model optional self dependence in mySQL wherein for instance a course may have one or more prerequisite(s) which are other courses in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a separate table which lists the course's prerequisites:

```
create table class_prerequisite (
   classID int not null,
   prerequisiteClass int not null,
   required bit not null default false,
   primary key (classID, prerequisiteClass)
);
```

where classID and prerequisiteClass are foreign keys pointing back at your classes table. The 'required' field would signal if it's a mandatory or optional prereq.

Comment: Allowing `prerequisite` to be NULL is typical to be able to say that there are no prerequisites.  `prerequisite` also wouldn't be part of the primary key -- it'd be a foreign key constraint to the same table.

Comment: allowing a null 'required' would imply that the prereq ID is indeed a prerequisite but you don't know if it's required. Schools are pretty hidebound and badly managed, but they do usually know what prereqs are suggestions and which are mandatory.

Comment: Then there wouldn't be a record in this table.

Comment: I will manage the enforcement of prerequisites at a higher level/layer in the software but needed to know how to represent it in db. thanks